# Visual Studio 2015 Community RC Cordova unable to delete image in contenteditable div

Tags: android, cordova, contenteditable, visual-studio-cordova, backspace

To regenerate the problem:

1. create a new Javascript Cordova project with Visual Studio 2015 Community RC or Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 with Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1
2. Replace the following code in index.html

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           function funAddImage() {
               divTest.innerHTML += '<img src="images/1.jpg" />'
           }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="divTest" contenteditable="true">1234</div>
       <div>
           <input type="button" value="Add Image" onclick="funAddImage()"/>
       </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Add an image 1.jpg in images folder.
4. Deploy the app in any android phone in debug mode or release mode with android version from 4.1.x to 4.4.x
5. After the app run in the mobile phone, **click "Add Image" button *TWO* times**.
6. Now move the cursor at the end of the last image and **PRESS BACKSPACE in the softkeyboard *TWO TIMES*.**

**Expected Result**: The 2 images are removed.

**Actual Result**:

Android 4.1.2 (Samsung Note 2) or 4.2.1 (A mobile phone with brand "ZOPO" made in China): **Only the last image is removed, the first image cannot be removed no matter how many times the BACKSPACE is pressed**.

Android 4.4.2 (Samsung Note 3 or another mobile phone with brand "Nubia" made in China): The letter 4 is removed, then the letter 3 is removed.  **Images CANNOT be removed by all means**.

**The purpose of this question**:

I want to develop an "Whatsapp" like chat app using VS 2015 Cordova, the message contains text and image, users should be able to edit the message before the message is sent.

Now, with this strange behavior, users are not able to remove any images added, what should I do?

PS: if I host the index.html in the IIS, and open the index.html in a PC desktop browser or any browser in the mobile phones mentioned above, the images can be removed as expected.

This problem is really important, if it cannot be solved, it means that Visual Studio Cordova is not capable of developing any apps with rich text editor.  (Or is there any other INPUT type that I can use to replace the contenteditable div?)

Answer (score 1):

Check my replies to your question opened on MSDN.

[Your MSDN question link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d9eda4ef-5531-401c-9097-16f0f0b9abb9/visual-studio-2015-community-rc-cordova-unable-to-delete-image-in-contenteditable-div?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova)

I don't think it's a cordova issue, but a android's web browser issue or the soft keyboard issue.

If I add some more characters after image to help locate the cursor, I can remove the image correctly. At least, it can be a workaround for you now.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your help, I've already reply in the MSDN, pls. check it.